# square payment form is not getting initialized and throws error

Tags: html

My code is as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>SnapBTC</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/intlTelInput.css">

   </head>

   <body>
   .....
   .....
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="build/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
      <script src="https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform"></script>
      <script src="js/basic.js"></script>
      <script src="js/squarePayment.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

squarePayment.js

```
var applicationId = 'sq0idp-EYeN-hglrwbhqPIuwJjFUA'; 

if (applicationId == '') {
  alert('You need to provide a value for the applicationId variable.');
}

var paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
  applicationId: applicationId,
  cardNumber: {
    elementId: 'ccnumber',
  },
  cvv: {
    elementId: 'cccvc',
    placeholder: 'CVV'
  },
  expirationDate: {
    elementId: 'ccexpdatemonth',
    placeholder: 'MM/YY'
  },
  postalCode: {
    elementId: 'postalcode'
  },
  callbacks: {

cardNonceResponseReceived: function(errors, nonce, cardData) {
  if (errors) {
    console.log("Encountered errors:");


    errors.forEach(function(error) {
      console.log('  ' + error.message);
    });

  } else {


    alert('Nonce received: ' + nonce);

  }
},

unsupportedBrowserDetected: function() {

},


inputEventReceived: function(inputEvent) {
  switch (inputEvent.eventType) {
    case 'focusClassAdded':
      // Handle as desired
      break;
    case 'focusClassRemoved':
      // Handle as desired
      break;
    case 'errorClassAdded':
      // Handle as desired
      break;
    case 'errorClassRemoved':
      // Handle as desired
      break;
    case 'cardBrandChanged':
      // Handle as desired
      break;
    case 'postalCodeChanged':
      // Handle as desired
      break;
  }
},

paymentFormLoaded: function() {

}
}
});

function requestCardNonce(event) {

  event.preventDefault();


  alert('method called: ');

  paymentForm.requestCardNonce();
}
```

But somehow, it throws error `The SqPaymentForm inputClass option is required.`  Is something wrong with integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so i just went to their documentation and checked, i think it's missing a required option, obviously we can't tell this for sure from the code you provided.

```
// Initializes the payment form. See the documentation for descriptions of
// each of these parameters.
var paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
  applicationId: applicationId,
  inputClass: 'sq-input', <----------------
  inputStyles: [
    {
      fontSize: '15px'
    }
  ],
```

[Source](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form)

> **inputClas** string
>
> This CSS class is assigned to all four of the iframes generated for the payment >form. You can create CSS rules for
> this class to style the exterior of the inputs (i.e., borders and
> margins). See Styling input exteriors for more information.

Comment: I have given squarePayment.js in my updated question. In that i have not provide `inputClass` and `input styles`. So is it the reason for failure?

Comment: From the error message, i suspect that is exactly the reason, please provide inputClass and see it fixes the problem. I have not used Square Pyamentform myself.